# Subprocess.run does not work in Docker, particularly for pdftotext (IO Error, file not found)

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, python-unittest, pdftotext

This works locally but not in a Docker container. I'm trying to run [pdftotext](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) in a docker container then unit-testing it on a pdf file. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the arguments required for `subprocess.run`. Is it not finding the directory of the pdf file or is the subprocess call just not working, or could it be an issue with docker?

I run `docker-compose up myproject python3 -m unittest`

My file structure:

```
├── myproject
├── ├── extract.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── testExtract.py
│   │   ├── testfiles
|   |   |   ├── sample.pdf
```

pdftotext method:

```
def extract(filepath)
    text = subprocess.run(['pdftotext', filepath],
                                stdout=PIPE,
                                stderr=STDOUT)
    text = str(fullText.stdout)
    return text
```

test method inside `testExtract.py`:

```
testGetText(self):
    expected = "b'Grab all text from this sentence.'"
    result = extract('./testfiles/sample.pdf')
    self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

sample.pdf only contains the above sentence.

When I set `stderr` to `STDOUT` I get an IO error displayed below. If I set to`stderr=subprocess.PIPE` I just get an empty binary string. `""`

traceback:

```
FAIL: testGetText 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

AssertionError: 'b"I/O Error: Couldn\'t open file \'./tes[51 chars]ry."' != "b'Grab all text from this sentence.'"
- b"I/O Error: Couldn't open file './testFiles/1SentenceFile.pdf': No such file or directory."
+ b'Grab all text from this sentence.'
```

Edit:
docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    myproject:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./myproject/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - database
        volumes:
            #- ./otherproject/logs:/code/logs
              # Dev specific
            - ./myproject:/code
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    database:
        # Possibly could do configurations here and skip database DOCKERFILE
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./database/Dockerfile
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /secrets/dbUser.txt
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /secrets/dbPassword.txt
        ports:
            - "8765:5432"
        volumes:
            - otherdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

myproject/dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    poppler-utils

ARG moduleDir=myproject

WORKDIR /code

COPY secrets/ /secrets

# COPY $moduleDir/myproject/ ./

# Is executed before bind mount is implemented so need to COPY.
COPY $moduleDir/requirements/common.txt requirements/common.txt
COPY $moduleDir/requirements/development.txt requirements/development.txt
COPY .pylintrc ./

RUN pip install -r requirements/development.txt
```

Comment: How do you run this method? Are you sure that the `.` in your directory is pointing to where you think it is?

Comment: @NiallByrne Hmm, I tried './tests/testFiles/1SentenceFile.pdf' and it returns an empty binary string, `AssertionError: "b''" != "b'Grab all text from this sentence.'"` without an error message. Perhaps it's able find the file, but something else is wrong?

Comment: @C.Nivs That could be it. Though when I try putting the test files in the same directory as the unittest and just do `1SentenceFile.pdf` it looks like it's able to find the file (doesn't return an I/O error) but returns an empty binary.

Comment: It might be more helpful to see what your `Dockerfile` looks like and what your `docker-compose.yaml` looks like so we can see exactly what's being called

Comment: @C.Nivs Added dockerfile and docker-compse.yml above.

Comment: I'm guessing that all of this code is executing from the `/code` directory, so `.` is `/code`, which doesn't have your directory in it

Comment: Thank you, I put my project inside `code` so it is `code/myproject` and it worked.